How to add "acknowledgements" in thesis in RMarkdown
I am using bookdown package for creating reports from multiple R Markdown files.
I want to include acknowledgements into my thesis. However, I have no idea why the content never appear... the rest working fine, such as abstract. Can anyone help... I am wondering the YAML acknowledgements is valid or not... The below is my attempt :
---
geometry: "left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
title: |
  Line1\
  Line2\
  Line3
author: |
  abc_123
acknowledgements: |
  `r paste(readLines("front-and-back-matter/_acknowledgements.Rmd"), collapse = '\n  ')`
abstract: |
  `r paste(readLines("front-and-back-matter/_abstract.Rmd"), collapse = "\n  ")`
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
---
# Preface

Pref1...PrefN
Pref1...PrefN

Pref1...PrefN

Outcome :

Moreover, here is how my _abstract.Rmd and _acknowledgements.Rmd looks like :
_abstract.Rmd:

_acknowledgements.Rmd:


Pandoc includes a front matter variable: thanks, which is placed as a footnote. So not sure if this would suit your purposes.  https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/6.2-variables.html

Hey @Peter , thanks for the sharing. I tried but not the one I looking for as this will place the acknowledgement in the footnote instead of the body :)

Why not create an acknowledgement in the document body using an unnumbered section heading? rather than in the yaml?

The top level entries in the YAML are mostly things processed by Pandoc, and they need to be in the default template to show up in the final document.  Is there documentation somewhere that says acknowledgments will be processed that way?  I was unable to find it.
I went looking for examples of bookdown documents with Acknowledgments sections, and found one here:  https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/tree/main/inst/examples .  This is the book, "bookdown: Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown".  It has an Acknowledgments section, but it is just a 2nd level entry in the index.Rmd file.  It is not mentioned in the YAML.
So that's what you should probably do.
EDITED to add:  In a comment, @Gambit mentioned they had seen this done in https://github.com/ulyngs/oxforddown/blob/master/index.Rmd, referenced from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBHxcuCMjnk .  The crucial thing is the specification of the template, in these lines:
https://github.com/ulyngs/oxforddown/blob/84c1e9bbf762dc58441a77d8f755e682ce89b763/index.Rmd#L16-L18
The template referenced in those lines appears to include a lot of entries that aren't supported by the default template.

Hey @user2554330 , I found from here ( https://github.com/ulyngs/oxforddown/blob/master/index.Rmd) that the acknowledgments can be processed in that way...
I actually reach the github from this YouTube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBHxcuCMjnk
